# Show Environment MachineName on Master Page SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, master-page

I'm working with SharePoint 2010. I am trying to show the Environment.MachineName variable in the Master Page. Any good examples online for doing this, as well as using XSLT variables or VBScript? I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantages of `Custom User Controls`. Custom user controls will give you all the power of C# you can utilize along with UI. You just need to register the custom user control in master page like `SharePoint`/`WebPartPage` etc. tag and use it in you body. Considering your environment if found a [tutorial](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/how-to-create-user-control-in-sharepoint2010.html), you can have look to this.